# Typedef struct pointer to function (C)

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, typedef

I am trying to pass a typedef struct pointer to a function and the compiler is complaining with this error message: **error: unknown type name ‘RootP’.** Here is the code...

```
int main()
{
    typedef struct Root
    {
        struct Root *child;
    }*RootP;
    RootP rootNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Root));
    rootNode->child = NULL;
    ....

}

void mkdir(RootP rootNode, char param2[60], char pwd[200])
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `struct` should be outside of `main`, so move

```
typedef struct Root
{
    struct Root *child;
 }*RootP;
```

before the `main` function. If the program is big enough, consider moving that into some header file (`*.h`)

And I would avoid using the `mkdir` name. It is defined in [Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html) and on Linux refers to the [mkdir(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) system call.

I don't feel that `typedef struct Root *RootP;` is pretty code: you usually want to see at a glance what C thing is a pointer. I would instead declare the `struct root_st` and have `typedef struct root_st Root;`  (Gtk also uses that, or a very similar, coding convention). And code `Root* rootnode`. But it is debatable and a matter of taste.

Comment: @xtofl I also liked your terse answer, you should undelete it :-)

Comment: Thanks all for the quick response and tips. I'm creating a simulated file system that accepts unix commands for class, reason for the mkdir.

Comment: Still, use another name, like `mymkdir`; it is making your code confusing.

Comment: If you keep the `mkdir` name and link with a library calling `mkdir` (and a lot of C libraries might do that) you'll have big, hard to hunt, bugs.